# Regular expression, omit few words

Tags: java, regex

How can I write a regular expression to match sth like that :

**he is** capable **of**

**he is** not capable **of**

etc

general pattern "he is" + up to few words + "of"

I know how to solve it without regular expression, but maybe there is easier way

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: What's your solution without regular expressions? And what regex have you come up with so far?

Comment: My solution is to find index of patterns "he is" and "of" and check how many characters are between, but it requires for loop

Comment: Something like `\bhe is\b(.*?)\bof\b` replace with `$1` I think would do it. That isn't looking for "few words" just anything in between.

Comment: What does sth mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with this:

```
\bhe is\b.*\bof\b
```

I'm using `\b` a lot to make sure I'm matching words. E.g. this won't match `She is capable of`, neither `he isa wizard capable of`

This is a little more complicated:

```
\bhe is\b( +\w+ *)*\bof\b
```

Here we have the `( +\w+ *)*` in the middle. This makes sure that it matches words after each other.

You can play with the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/citDxc/1).

Answer (score 2):

A trivial solution would be to use

```
\bhe is(?: \w+){1,3} of\b
```

which allows between one and three "words" between `he is` and `of`.

`\w+` means "a sequence of letters/digits/underscores", so it doesn't exactly match a word, but you can substitute your own word-matching regex if that one is too unspecific.

The `\b` [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) are used to only match `he` and `of` and not `the` or `often`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to check if there is the capable or the not capatable.

```
"he is\\s+(not\\s+)?(capable\\s+)?of"
```